# Querying an event store

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I've been developing software for a number of years and have found the event store concept to be quite interesting, as it will neatly avoid a number of pain points I've encountered over the years. However, three things remain for me before I can really give this a go.

The first is, how to handle querying an event store. Now, I understand that you would basically support such queries by setting up tables that essentially cache results from the stream of events, probably in a denormalized fashion. How would you implement that though? Would you just have another listener for the event that updates the table? What if you are allowing search for practically any field on a particular object? When you update the schema that is used in the search table, wouldn't you have to rerun whatever updates the table for all records? How hard is this to pull off cleanly?

The second is, how do you handle large chunks of data? That is, lets say you are storing blog posts and the like. How do you deal with an arbitrarily large wad of text that receives a fair number of updates? Would you just run the new version through something that produces a diff against the old version, or would you use another strategy?

The third is, how do you handle bulk updates from outside? Let's say that large documents come in and each represents an aggregate root. Do you break it up into a series of smaller updates (and potentially lose sight of how it came in through a bulk update), or do you just have a massive, nasty event for this particular use case.

I realize almost all of the above are just begging for an answer of "it depends". But what's the general approach?

Comment: Mate, way too many questions. They are simply not answerable as this blob. BTW I'd recommend reading the archives of the DDD/CQRS mailing list for a bit and/or looking at a tutorial on Event Sourcing. QAs: You don't query an event store in the way you think - it has intrinsic support for loading an aggregate worth (w/ or w/o snapshotting. You denormalize into queryable format on the projection side which is typically dispatched to via a bus or similar. How do you write a wordprocessor with undo - hard to say on SO!? Go look at samples for the Event Store to get a feel for it I reckon.

Comment: My main issue was the querying. I guess the others are so implementation-specific as to not be particularly useful at the moment. But on the first one, do you just have something listening for those messages and updating a persistent store, have an out of band process do it, or what? And how do you keep the read side consistent, since it isn't the authoritative source of the data?

Comment: Need to at-reply if you want people to reply in a timely fashion. I assume your questions were resolved from the DDD/CQRS thread? Taking NEventStore, there is a dispatcher which is handed new messages. Then, it depends. Some (most? v hard to generalize due to the ID factor!) users implement a Dispatcher which places the message on a bus (generally durable and generally needs to maintain ordering semantics but ID). The read side will be ***Eventually** Consistent* - remember, doing any of the Projections in a transaction with the Dispatching is **Wrong** (and missing the point).

Comment: The single thing that's authoritative is the events that have happened. When processing on an Event Sourced Aggregate, you get a consistent set of events preceding the Command and the command processing can generate new events (and e.g. if there are conflicting commands, one will need to 'lose' and be retried). The published events as handed to the Dispatcher by the Event Store are the *only* stream of the 'agreed truth' as it should be observed from outside. While there are querying mechanisms that make it look like this is only one way of looking at it, you'll find that most of the querying

Comment: APIs in NEventStore are intended to facilitate building an appropriate Projection layer (some people do in-memory models etc., in which case on startup the process will load up all relevant events rather than relying on persistent projection storage). With GetEventStore, the design provides a generalized streams mechanism which unifies Aggregate Streams, Dispatcher Queues, Projection Buses/Queues, Projection State (and multiple layers thereof). But the bottom line there is once again the same - you set up async processing to project the events - you don't answer Read questions by querying evts

Comment: http://vimeo.com/84314441